# What is a good method to create generic plot function which can create different types of charts?

Tags: r, plot

I was going to create a generic plot function for my package and I was wondering what is a good method to create two types of graph depending on what is passed to it?  I'm hoping to submit my project to CRAN later on in the year.

For example:

```
plot.myclass <- function(x, type){
    if(type[1] == "bar"){
        #plot bar chart...
     } else{
        #plot scatter...
     }
}
```

Comment: Depends on your opinion of `plot`.

Comment: No one at CRAN will really care, but it might make more sense to make a `plot` method for the scatterplot and `barplot` method for the bar plot.

Comment: Yeah, actually, if you're building your own classes, methods for the base functions are a good option.

Comment: Oh brilliant! Thanks for the quick response, just realised how silly I was being about the barplot!

Comment: What you propose is pretty much standard practice.  No one will be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

ggplot2 alternative:

```
plot.myclass <- function(x, type){
    if(type[1] == "bar"){
        p <- ggplot(barplot)
     } else{
        p <- ggplot(hist)
     }
return(plot(p))
}

plotItOut <- plot.myclass(x,type)
```